# How to activate the window that comes with idea through code?

Tags: intellij-plugin

I want to develop a plugin that prints in the console window, but I don't want to customize the Tool Window component。

This is how I currently do it:

```
ToolWindow toolWindow = ToolWindowManager.getInstance(e.getProject()).getToolWindow("Run");
toolWindow.show(); 

ContentManager contentManager = toolWindow.getContentManager();
ConsoleView consoleView = TextConsoleBuilderFactory.getInstance().createBuilder(e.getProject()).getConsole();
Content content = contentManager.getFactory().createContent(consoleView.getComponent(), "Generator", false);
contentManager.addContent(content );

contentManager.setSelectedContent(content);
consoleView.print(text, ConsoleViewContentType.NORMAL_OUTPUT);
consoleView.scrollTo(consoleView.getContentSize()-1);
```

But I found that if the window is not activated, the **getToolWindow** method gets null。
Is it possible to activate the window directly by means of code, rather than by activate it from the View -> Tool Windows menu？